# Mocking constants inside method in Jasmine(AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have some methods in my services that declare constants; I would like to mock values for those constants when testing the method in Jasmine. For example, lets suppose exampleService.js has the method bellow:

```js
function multiply (number) {
  const multiplier = 2;
  return number * multiplier;
 }
```

And then I want to test the method but I want Jasmine to set multiplier to 3, so I can write my test like

```js
describe('.multiply()', () => {
  it('should return argument times multiplier', () => {
    const numberArgument = 4;
    const multiplier = 3;
    /* set the multiplier for the test */
    const expectedResult = 12;
    const actualResult = testService.multiply(numberArgument);
    
    expect(actualResult).toEqual(expectedResult);
  });
});
```

How can I do the *set the multiplier for the test* part?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You won't be able to mock this; why not pass the multiplier as a second argument?

Comment: This was just an example. In the actual application(legacy as hell) we have lots of methods structured in this way. Also, the factories and controllers have a lot of constants, which would be nice to mock for some tests. But I think that this functionality not being provided is a strong sign that we should refactor the application bit by bit. Thanks, anyway! \o